# Showing Current date in Yii input form

Tags: php, yii

I have an input form for date input.I have used Datetime Picker for input date.I have used this code for input date field.

```
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Form_issue_date'); ?>
  <?php 
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
  array(
        'attribute'=>'Form_issue_date',
        'model'=>$model,
        'options' => array(
                          'mode'=>'focus',
                          'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                          'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                          ),
  'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date'),
      )
  );
  ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'Form_issue_date'); ?>
</div>
```

Now I want that the same input field will be there but current date should be seen on the input form area by default.If any user wants to change the date then he will click on that, after that the date picker should come and in that the user will change the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the `value` field to your `htmlOptions` of the CJuiDatePicker, so your code is:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
 array(
    'attribute'=>'Form_issue_date',
    'model'=>$model,
    'options' => array(
                      'mode'=>'focus',
                      'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                      'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
                      ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>30,'class'=>'date', 'value'=>date("d F, Y")),
 )
);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
 array(
    'attribute'=>'Form_issue_date',
    'model'=>$model,
    'options' => array(
                      'mode'=>'focus',
                      'dateFormat'=>'d MM, yy',
                      'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                      'size'=>15,
                      'class'=>'date',
                      'value'=>date("d F, Y")
    ),
 )
);
```

Comment: Hi @user4295737, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer can be more people-friendly with some explanation of what changes you've made, etc.